# Linux writing GPU drivers to print arbitrary outputs from kernel side

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, framebuffer, gpu

I have questions about GPU drivers for linux kernel.

**1-) Is it possible to write a custom kernel module to print words or colors on screen like VGA using a GPU over PCI express ?**

**2-) If it is, is it generic or device/chip dependent?**

**3-) If it is, is it possible with writing MMIO space?**

What is on my mind is, I want to write a simple kernel module to print some arbitrary values over PCI express bus. My GPU is only have mDP and DVI-D outputs and it has a big kernel driver in linux kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First; let's split a video card into multiple different pieces:

- video RAM (and probably some ROM for BIOS and/or UEFI that's used during boot, that we can ignore because it's useless after boot)
- something that controls video RAM, converts physical accesses into VRAM accesses, may include "stealing of system RAM" (for integrated video), and probably includes some kind of DMA engine (to accelerate the transfer of data between system RAM and video RAM)
- something that controls video signals being sent to a monitor (video mode timings), and pumps pixel data from frame buffer to a (VGA, DVI, HDMI, ...) socket, and is able to obtain information (EDID/Extended Display Identification Data) from the monitor. Note that if a video card supports multiple monitors all of this would have to be duplicated multiple times.
- various fixed function accelerators - e.g. MPEG decoder.
- a "processor unit" that executes some kind of machine code and does things. This is the GPU; and is typically used to execute programs that were compiled elsewhere (e.g. by video driver) from a more portable language (HLSL, GLSL, C) and used for shaders and GPGPU.

> 1-) Is it possible to write a custom kernel module to print words or colors on screen like VGA using a GPU over PCI express ?

In theory; yes. In practice it'd be far easier to do it without using the GPU (just writing pixel data directly to video RAM/frame buffer using the CPU instead), partly because using GPUs is unnecessary overkill, and partly because the compilers needed for "portability to different GPUs" are in user-space and not in the kernel. However this is mostly silly anyway - there's no guarantee that whatever is actually using the frame buffer (e.g. maybe a full screen game) won't overwrite whatever the kernel does before its sent to the monitor and no guarantee that the user will ever be able to see whatever the kernel did.

> 2-) If it is, is it generic or device/chip dependent?

It's very device/chip dependent; and also very "situation dependent" (e.g. depending on how other software in user-space, like Gnome or KDE or Wine or ..., is currently using the video card).

> 3-) If it is, is it possible with writing MMIO space?

Yes (but "MMIO" includes frame buffer, memory used for textures, and all of the internal control registers for all of the pieces of a video card). It's probably also possible to teach someone to play the piano by stabbing their brain with needles/electrodes - "possible" does NOT mean "easy" or "sensible".

---

To do what I think your goal is properly; you'd probably want to modify all "video card drivers" (where "video card driver" in Linux is many pieces strewn all over the place, with parts in kernel and parts in user-space libraries; where some parts are likely proprietary/closed source); so that the video card driver is responsible for setting up a "reserved for kernel only" overlay (that is super-imposed on top of whatever user-space wanted to display, for each different monitor). However, even in that case it probably can't work for some cases (old and/or low-end video cards often found in servers that can't support overlays, remote desktop where you're using something like RDP or X over a network and not a video card, video cards being used for "PCI passthrough" by hyper-visors/virtual machines).

Comment: Hello @Brendan, thanks for this elegant question. Does virtual VRAM is the same thing with MMIO space arranged for GPU PCIe in CPUs physical memory map? and if everything is device dependent, at low level, vendors kernel drivers must be working if we want use GPU to draw something. As I understood so far, there will be no generic driver or userspace program to make VGA emulation?

Comment: @YusufAltıparmak: For "virtual VRAM", I'm not sure what you're asking. You will need working driver code to do video mode switches, use fixed function accelerators, and use the GPU; but (as long as nothing else is doing anything with video) you can have generic code that draws pixels (using CPU) directly into frame buffer; and often this is how things work during boot (with BIOS or UEFI being used to set a video mode and get information about the video mode that's needed to figure out how to draw pixels)..

Comment: @YusufAltıparmak: For VGA emulation (at the hardware level); the first problem is that it used fixed IO ports, which makes it unusable when there's multiple monitors because you can't have 2 things using the same IO ports. For BIOS systems often the video card's controls for one monitor was left in a "VGA compatible-ish emulation mode" at boot; but for UEFI there's no point doing that so video card manufacturers don't bother. There's no other generic interface at the hardware level - to set a video mode you need driver code (in OS/kernel, or in firmware/video ROM that can be used during boot).